# How to change the color of the grid lines and how to change the position of tick lines?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am building a code to show the area between the two functions below. It's good but it can get better.

[image]

My questions are: is there a way to move the x tick labels (the numbers on the x axis) a little to the left so that the guideline doesn't cross it? Also do the same thing with the y-tick labels (a little below)? And how can I change the color of the guidelines and the x and y intervals for the guideline grid matrix?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Eixos
\begin{axis}[
grid,
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xtick={-1,0,1},
ytick={-1,0,1},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={below right},
ylabel style={above left},
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=1.1,
ymin=-0.5,
ymax=1.1]

% Função de cima contínua
\addplot[name path=f,domain=0:1,CCazul] {x};
% Função de baixo cintínua
\addplot[name path=g,domain=0:1,CCvermelho] {x^2};

% Função de cima pontilhada
\addplot[dashed, name path=fpont1,domain=-.5:0,CCazul] {x};
\addplot[dashed, name path=fpont2,domain=1:1.1,CCazul] {x};
% Função de baixo pontilhada
\addplot[dashed, name path=gpont1,domain=-.5:0,CCvermelho] {x^2};    
\addplot[dashed, name path=gpont2,domain=1:1.1,CCvermelho] {x^2};   

% Path
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);

%Fill between
\addplot [
thick,
color=black,
fill=black, 
fill opacity=0.05
]
fill between[
of=f and g,
soft clip={domain=0:1},
];

% Labels dos nós
\node [color=CCazul] at (axis cs:  .55,  .8) {$f(x) = x$};
\node  [color=CCvermelho] at (axis cs:  0.9,  .4) {$g(x) = x^2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please complete your MWE, that it can be compiled. You haven't define colors. Beside this you have an error in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify `xticklabel style={below left}` to offset the x tick label, same for the y axis.

To change apperance of the gridlines, specify `grid style={...}`.

To change intervals between grid lines, you can specify `minor tick num`, or `minor x tick num` and `minor y tick num` if the intervals are not the same for both.

Example (I changed `CCazul` to `blue` and `CCvermelho` to `red` since you left out the defintion of these colors):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
grid=both,
grid style={red!15},
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xtick={-1,0,1},
ytick={-1,0,1},
minor tick num=4,
xticklabel style={below left},
yticklabel style={below left},
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
xlabel style={below right},
ylabel style={above left},
xmin=-0.5,
xmax=1.1,
ymin=-0.5,
ymax=1.1]

\addplot[name path=f,domain=0:1,blue] {x};

\addplot[name path=g,domain=0:1,red] {x^2};

\addplot[dashed, name path=fpont1,domain=-.5:0,blue] {x};
\addplot[dashed, name path=fpont2,domain=1:1.1,blue] {x};

\addplot[dashed, name path=gpont1,domain=-.5:0,red] {x^2};    
\addplot[dashed, name path=gpont2,domain=1:1.1,red] {x^2};   

% Path
\path[name path=axis] (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:1,0);

%Fill between
\addplot [
thick,
color=black,
fill=black, 
fill opacity=0.05
]
fill between[
of=f and g,
soft clip={domain=0:1},
];

\node[blue] at (axis cs:  .55,  .8) {$f(x) = x$};
\node[red] at (axis cs:  0.9,  .4) {$g(x) = x^2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: thank you, your answer was perfect. Have a great Sunday, best regards.